# Window: target window already closed

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to do an automatic screenshot, but i kept getting this.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already
> closed

> from unknown error: web view not found
> (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.100)

Here is the code that I use.

```
DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=directory')  
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=DRIVER")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

url = :'https://www.instagram.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
```

Is there anyway to fix it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You have couple of options, you can try waiting for the window to load completely before taking the screenshot, adding a delay before taking the screenshot, or handling the exception and retrying to take the screenshot after a short delay

I can also write some code about each one if you want

Comment: Thank you @Goran, it works! I just had to add the wait and closed windows command